# Is it necessary to create <span> elements to register event listeners

Tags: event-handling, addeventlistener, event-bubbling

I have a working web app that reads local .txt files and displays the content in a div element. I create a span element out of each word because I need to be able to select any word in the document and create an EEI (Essential Elements of Information) from the text. I then register a click handler on the containing div and let the event bubble up. The three functions below show reading the file, and parsing it, and populating the text div with spans:

```
    function readInputFile(evt) {
    reset();
    var theFile = evt.target.files[0];
    if(theFile) {
        $("#theDoc").empty(); //Clean up any old docs loaded
        var myReader = new FileReader();
        var ta = document.getElementById("theDoc");
        myReader.onload = function(e) {
            parseTheDoc(e.target.result);
            initialMarkup();
        };
        myReader.readAsText(theFile);
    } else {
        alert("Can not read input file: readInputFile()");
    }
}

    function parseTheDoc(docContents) {
    var lines = docContents.split("\n");
    var sentWords =[];
    for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        sentWords = lines[i].split(" ");
        words = words.concat(sentWords);
        words.push("<br>");
    }
    //examineWords(words);
    createSpans(words);
}

   function createSpans() {
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        var currentWord = words[i];
        if(currentWord !== "<br>") {
            var $mySpan = $("<span />");
            $mySpan.text(currentWord + " ");
            $mySpan.attr("id", "word_" + i);
            $("#theDoc").append($mySpan);
            buildDocVector(currentWord, i, $mySpan);
        }
        else {
            var $myBreak = $("<br>");
            $myBreak.attr("id", "word_" + i);
            $("#theDoc").append($myBreak);
            buildDocVector("br", i, $myBreak);

        }
    }
    //console.log("CreateSpans: Debug");
}
```

So basically a simple fileReader, split on \n, then tokenize on white space. I then create a span for each word, and a br element for each \n. It's not beautiful, but it satisfies the requirement, and works. My question is, is there a more efficient way of doing this? It just seems expensive to create all these spans, but my requirement is to annotate the doc and map any selected word to a data model/ontology. I can't think of a way to allow the user to select any word, or combination of words (control click) and then perform operations on them. This works, but with large docs (100 pages) I start having performance/memory issues. I understand this is more a design question and may not be appropriate, but I'd really like to know if there are more performant solutions.

Comment: Elements are basically the smallest identifiable unit.  So yes, you have to create `spans` or some other element.  To resolve the performance issues with large documents, you need to avoid rendering the pages that are not visible.  Either moving to a paging model where the user explicitly renders only 1 (or 2 or 4) pages at a time, or you need to add logic to check the user's scroll position and only render empty divs for all of the pages out of view instead of rendering their content.

Comment: Thank you. Just needed a sanity check. I was already implementing the "Render only what's visible" idea when I thought I'd ask if there was an alternative. Appreciate the quick response.